# How to Start Process in Background

Tags: command-line, bash, wget, background-process

I want to emphasize that I said ***start*** process in background in Linux. I didn't say start process in foreground, then move it to background, just to re-emphasize.

When I run `wget "http://blawblaw.blaw/blaw.html" &`, it starts the download, but it also still displays the results on my terminal still.

If I start the command, then terminate it mid-process using control+Z, then run `bg`, it finishes it, but still shows results in the terminal.

I've also tried `` `wget "http://someth.ing/html"` & `` and `nohup "http://someth.ing/html" &`, and all sorts of different ways from these tutorials on how to "start a process in background" (which is false in these tutorials, since it starts in the foreground then gets sent to the background), and they either lock my terminal into showing the results or they get sent to the background and terminate as soon as a type in any other commands in the terminal.

Also, the control+Z solution doesn't work too well for me, as I need this to eventually program this to do it automatically for me within BASH, and I can't make BASH do control+Z.

I have also tried doing `>/dev/null` to write it to the null device, and it still has this issue.

Comment: "start in the background" != "send output where I can't see it"

Answer (score 2):

How about `wget -b URL`

It's on the man page